# Hide a part on drupal checkout page

Tags: drupal, ubercart

On the website www.heinz-ols.com you can buy credits for car tuning.
A rule has been setup that only belgium users should pay 21% taxes. Everyone else in the world, doesn't have to pay taxes. The rule works, but it is only active on the checkout page after you entered your billing address.

Now buyers outside belgium already see 21% taxes added to the total and it will be gone after they entered their billing address. This scares people to continue buying the products.

How can the taxes be hidden untill the address is given?

It's made with drupal and ubercart.

Could I hide the payment methode on the checkout page until the address is given?
Or does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some conditions to the rule for the tax. You need to check/track the user's location, and based on it, trigger the rule. If you are already asking for location details, you need to compare field values